# Problems aligning table in 2-column format from journal template

Tags: tables, align, templates

I am having a lot of trouble aligning a table (see attachment) in a single column of a 2-column format from a template provided by the MBE journal:

https://academic.oup.com/mbe/pages/General_Author_Guidelines#LaTeX%20Submissions.

The zip file in "available here as a .zip file" contains all relevant files for the compilation.

[image]

I used the same code of the template for the table. This is a compilable code that gives me the same error messages (I use Texmaker):

```
\documentclass[nogrid]{MBE}%
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Added by LV
\jshort{mst}
\volname{}
\jvolume{0}
\jvol{}
\jissue{0}
\pubyear{2019}
\mstype{Article}
\artid{012}

%\access{Advance Access publication March 3, 2013}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\keyword{keywords}
\maketitle

\section*{Results}  

\subsection*{Associations}  

Here I cite \textbf{Table \ref{tab2}}).

\begin{table}[!t]%1
%\begin{center}
\tableparts{
\caption{Association between ... and ...} * Significantly associated.
%\end{center}
\label{tab2}}

{\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lld{5,0}d{5,0}@{}}\toprule 
SNP ID & \mcc{\textit{P}-value} & \mcc{Significance threshold} \\\colrule 

rs2276440 & \mcc{0.060}& \mcc{\hspace*{5pt}$0.0500$}\\
[0.1pt]
rs10924824 & \mcc{0.140} & \mcc{\hspace*{5pt}$0.0050$} \\\botrule
\end{tabular*}}
{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion is welcome. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you post a compilable code?

Comment: If I try to compile your code, I obtain several error messages such as ' Paragraph ended before \@settodim was complete'. In order to get a compilable code, I simply removed the empty line inside of the `tabular*` environment (line 36) and obtained the following result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/p15Lm.png Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?